# Отсроченная загрузка файла nestjs Multer

Tags: файлы, nestjs, multer

Столкнулся с проблемой, при получении файла на сервере отрабатывает middleware от multer, после чего файл загружается на диск. Но как сделать так, чтобы он не загружался сразу? Допустим если я загружаю файл к продукту, которого не существует то выьрасывается ошибка что его не существует, а файл уже загружен, но по сколько нет продукта, то мне нужно чтобы этот файл не загружался. Может можно как то отложить загрузку на диск или как то замечать ошибки, которые могут произойти в сервисе?